# recuperar dados de um node Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Glr, eu quero recuperar um dado no Firebase que está dentro de um node. Alguem pode me dar uma Luz ?
Obs.: Esse tópico ja existe aq e eu ja vi uma solução, porém o autor da resposta descreve um método que não mais existe no Firebase devido a atualizações.. Estou usando a imagem desse mesmo tópico pois o problema é o mesmo. Pela imagem vê se essa estrutura e oq eu quero é recuperar o nome do user

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou com o método `child( "Notificas" ).child("Usuarios").child("ID")` ?

Comment: Que resposta é essa que não funciona mais? Explique o que já tentou pois há o perigo de receber uma resposta igual à que você já fez.

Comment: então, na resposta q foi dada é dito o uso de uma classe FirebaseConfig, olhei a documentação ao q parece essa classe foi reformulada, tendo alguns métodos modificados.. Instanciei a nova classe mas n achei os mesmo métodos. Logo tirei a conclusão de que a solução se tornou obsoleta

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, sim, porem oq acontece é que eu preciso pegar o ID do usuario para chegar ate o campo Nome e isso tb n estou conseguindo fazer.. Veja bem, Tenho uma activity Login q recolhe os dados passados, cria um novo usuario e o armazena no Firebase, em seguida, vou pra a activity Main onde possui 4 Fragments. É nesse fragment q estou tentando recuperar os dados do usuario

Comment: @IagoNogueira Quando você sair da `activity login` para `activity main`, passe o valor do "ID" como argumento ou utiliza `SharedPreferences` para salvar o valor e consulta-lo posteriormente. Dessa forma você consegue fazer como citei no primeiro comentário.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br